# Why is blkid displaying a different UUID than /dev/disk/by-uuid for my USB drive

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 and want to automount a USB drive on startup while using an external HDD as root filesystem (see the [post on Raspberry Pi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34433/usb-drive-not-automounted-when-booting-from-external-hdd) for further information).

Among others I tried to mount it by UUID but while blkid returns

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="GIT" UUID="3a20b6ab-f7cb-44a4-9437-23b8ba33fef2" TYPE="ext4"
```

/dev/disk/by-uuid contains the following

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan  1  1970 66a72c4f-1a9b-47ad-99b7-3040ab1f79f6 -> ../../sda1
```

I already tried to change the UUID of my USB drive by using `tune2fs /dev/{device} -U {uuid}` but to no avail.

So, how could it be that blkid and /dev/disk/by-uuid return different UUIDS for my USB drive and how can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe try running `partprobe` and/or `hdparm -z` to make sure your kernel is in sync with the disk.  Also maybe `udevadm trigger`.  Not saying these will fix your problem, but then at least we can rule out some weird transient condition.

Comment: Also, what does `dumpe2fs /dev/sda1` report for the UUID?

Comment: I ran all commands. Still no change. dumpe2fs reports the same UUID as /dev/disk/by-uuid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given what `dumpe2fs` is reporting, it must be the case that `blkid` is wrong and the others are correct.  This isn't so surprising because `blkid` maintains a cache.  If you run `blkid -g` or `blkid -p /dev/sda1` as root it will probably bypass or fix the cache and agree with the other two results.  You can also blow away the cache file, which is often in `/run/blkid/blkid.tab`.

Comment: Or just have blkid read the cache from /dev/null: `blkid -c /dev/null`